# How to Find similar DB queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So we have few of our apps running parameterized DB queries  dynamically , which means they are same queries but few content changes (and there are numerous unknown variations), to give example:

query 1 :

```
create table table-name-123-a-bcns-asns 
select * something something
query continues
WHERE date = '2019-01-01'
```

query 2 :

```
create table table-name-a2da-asdsec-oio2 
select * something something
query continues
WHERE date = '2019-01-02'
```

if you see, they are same queries with only new temporary table names and dates. we want to find how many unique queries we have (assume above are 1, not 2 queries)

Any suggestions would be really very much appreciated.

Comment: You have to have some kind of MySQL proxy or router which can log these queries and match those.

Answer (score 1):

If all your queries are CTAs(CREATE TABLE AS) then you could check metadata:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFROMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name LIKE 'table-name-%'
```

Comment: we dont have metadata, they are submitted from applications which are hosted outside and we dont have access to. we just get queries submitted, and on top of that we are talking about thousands of applications, which are using their own schemas. :(

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is always available. If table is not dropped directly after creation you could search it.